# Newbie here: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, jupyter-lab

Im a total noob, and Ive been trying to fix this issue for 2 days now and always get stuck. Im trying to get chromedriver running through anaconda in JupyterLab. Any advice on this issue?

```
wd = wd.Chrome()
wd.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Gives me this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

I understand the issue, but I have had no succsess with several attempts at fixing it; as said Im a total beginner and lack in basic knowledge, so any detailed help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's needed to provide path to the chrome binary, e.g. in following way:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

# create selenium driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>', options=chrome_options)

# open web page
driver.get('<URL>')

# quit driver
#driver.quit()
```

Executable can be downloaded [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).
Selenium tutorial for python is available [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).